# returning the lowest point in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def find_local_sink(m: List[List[int]], start: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    """
    Examples 
    >>> m = [[ 5,70,71,80],
             [50, 4,30,90],
             [60, 3,35,95],
             [10,72, 2, 1]]
    >>> find_local_sink(m, [0,0])
    [3,3]
    >>> m = [[ 5,70,71,80],
             [50, 4, 5,90],
             [60, 3,35, 2],
             [ 1,72, 6, 3]]
    >>> find_local_sink(m, [0,3])
    [2,3]
    >>> m = [[9,2,3],
             [6,1,7],
             [5,4,8]]
    >>> find_local_sink(m, [1,1])
    [1,1]
    """
    lowest_point = m[0][0]
    for i in range(len(m)):
        for j in range(len(m)):
            if m[i][j] < lowest_point:
                lowest_point = m[i][j]
                print(lowest_point)
    return find_local_sink
```

Given a list or point. i want to return the next lowest point. I am trying to figure how to even do that. Alot of the docstring are test cases to show the desired out intend. The problem is it doesnt return the next smallest item, rather it returns the overall smallest. All it doesnt return the index, rather only the value does it return

Comment: Offhand, the code looks correct. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Okay i didnt explain properly. It doesnt return the next smallest item, rather it returns the overall smallest. All it doesnt return the index, rather only the value does it return

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you elaborate?

Comment: What does `next lowest point` mean? How is `next` calculated? Is it "next" based on the vertical `i` index? the horizontal `j` index? Like the others say, the question is not clear.

Comment: You start looping from `i = 0 .. len(m) - 1` and `j = 0 .. len(m) - 1`. That means you're looping through all the data, maybe try to confine your search by modifying the range? I don't know how to help if the question isn't clear.

Comment: Currently,  your code doesn't seem correctly indented. You don't use your start parameter, perhaps that is part of your problem with finding only the overall minimum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't use the `start` parameter, that's why it prints the overall minimum. Change the range in your `for`-loops to use `start`'s elements as start values.
Also, the function should return `lowest_point` if you need the value; if you need the indices use an extra variable to track them:

```
def find_local_sink(m, start):
    lowest_point = m[start[0]][start[1]]
    lowest_index = [[start[0], start[1]]
    for i in range(start[0], len(m)):
        for j in range(start[1], len(m)):
            if m[i][j] < lowest_point:
                lowest_point = m[i][j]
                lowest_index = [i, j]
    return lowest_index # or: return lowest_point
```